# Matching a line to a rule in c++

Tags: string, algorithm, line, matching

I have a line and a set of rules (other lines). Line to match (line = rule) may be very long; set of rules may be large and each rule may be long. Shorter rules may be part of longer (need to choose longer).
Currently, I have about 70 rules, <30 characters long, organized in a long if-else-if chain.
Is there any way to predict at what point there will be decrease in performance?
Is there a faster way of matching that comparing line with each of the rules?

Edit: There are no text files. I have an encoded sequence of characters, I go through if-elses comparing to "rules", and then act accordingly.

Comment: Do you mean you have a text-file with "rules" and want to match a line in that file?

Comment: Are you able to split the string to fixed parts? What do these strings and rules look like?

Comment: What does the comparison entail? Equality? Substring?

Comment: Equality.
The string may look like niVVVd__xniVVd__ or niVVVdxniVVd. And there is a rule niVVdxniVVd. If the line and rule are equal, then I decode the line and do something else.

Comment: Sounds like the rules are hardcoded. Maybe you could put them in a map and sort it by rule length (reverse order so that longest is first), then just iterate the rules looking for a match in a for loop. This way you don't need to add more if else groups, just add a new rule to the map. The map would map rules to function pointers and when you get a rule match, call the function.

Comment: C++ does not have any concept of a "line", or a "rule". There is such a thing as a predicate. And where exactly does C++ come into this?

Comment: pstrjds, thanks, that might work!
CashCow, "rules" are in quotes: you may call it matching a string to one of the strings in a given set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just check whether the input line is equal to any of the lines rules, then use an `std::set` (or `std::map`, if you want different behavior per rule) to store them. That takes the matching complexity down to O(lg *N*) where *N* is the number of rules.

Better yet, use an `unordered_set` (C++11) for O(1) performance.

If the behavior does not depend on which rule matched, then you can also compile a regular expression from the rules (e.g. `(niVVVd__xniVVd__)|(niVVVdxniVVd)`) with a tool like [RE2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) to get worst-case O(*n*) behavior, where *n* is the length of the input string.

Since you're comparing for equality, you don't need to match the longest rule first.